# Returning Array from Recursive Binary Tree Search

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

Hi I've made a simple Binary Tree and added a pre-order traversal method. After throwing around some ideas I got stuck on finding a way to return each value from the `traverse_pre()` method in an array.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def add_child(self, val):
        if self.value:
            if val < self.value:
                if self.left == None:
                    self.left = BST(val)
                else:
                    self.left.add_child(val)
            else:
                if val > self.value:
                    if self.right == None:
                        self.right = BST(val)
                    else:
                        self.right.add_child(val)
        else:
            self.value = val

    def traverse_pre(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.traverse_pre()
        print(self.value)

        if self.right:
            self.right.traverse_pre()


Tree = BST(5)
Tree.add_child(10)
Tree.add_child(8)
Tree.add_child(2)
Tree.add_child(4)
Tree.add_child(7)

Tree.traverse_pre()
```

How would I modify the `traverse_pre()` function to return an array consisting of the node values. Is there a good example of this process for me to understand this further, I'm a bit stuck on how values can be appended to an array within recursion.

Comment: What do you mean by an array?  Do you want a list of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend copying the entire tree to an intermediate list using  `.append` or `.extend`. Instead use `yield` which makes your tree iterable and capable of working directly with many built-in Python functions -

```py
class BST:
    # ...
    def preorder(self):
        # value
        yield self.value
        # left
        if self.left: yield from self.left.preorder()
        # right
        if self.right: yield from self.right.preorder()
```

We can simply reorder the lines this to offer different traversals like `inorder` -

```py
class BST:
    # ...
    def inorder(self):
        # left
        if self.left: yield from self.left.inorder()
        # value
        yield self.value
        # right
        if self.right: yield from self.right.inorder()
```

And `postorder` -

```py
class BST:
    # ...
    def postorder(self):
        # left
        if self.left: yield from self.left.postorder()
        # right
        if self.right: yield from self.right.postorder()
        # value
        yield self.value
```

Usage of generators provides inversion of control. Rather than the traversal function deciding what happens to each node, the the caller is left with the decision on what to do. If a list is indeed the desired target, simply use `list` -

```py
list(mytree.preorder())
```

```py
# => [ ... ]
```

That said, there's room for improvement with the rest of your code. There's no need to mutate nodes and tangle `self` context and recursive methods within your `BST` class directly. A functional approach with a thin `class` wrapper will make it easier for you to grow the functionality of your tree. For more information on this technique, see [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340109/633183).

If you need to facilitate trees of significant size, a different traversal technique may be required. Just ask in the comments and someone can help you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it - all branches return their lists of subelements.

In case a node has no subelements, it only returns its own value. Otherwise, it also contains elements from the children.

Extend adds all elements from the child node result list to the parent node result list.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def add_child(self, val):
        if self.value:
            if val < self.value:
                if self.left == None:
                    self.left = BST(val)
                else:
                    self.left.add_child(val)
            else:
                if val > self.value:
                    if self.right == None:
                        self.right = BST(val)
                    else:
                        self.right.add_child(val)
        else:
            self.value = val

    def traverse_pre(self):
        results = []

        if self.left:
            results.extend(self.left.traverse_pre())

        results.append(self.value)

        if self.right:
            results.extend(self.right.traverse_pre())

        return results


Tree = BST(5)
Tree.add_child(10)
Tree.add_child(8)
Tree.add_child(2)
Tree.add_child(4)
Tree.add_child(7)

print(Tree.traverse_pre())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array as a global variable and in the traverse_pre() function you can append the value to that array, instead of print it out.

```
arr = []
class BST:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def add_child(self, val):
        if self.value:
            if val < self.value:
                if self.left == None:
                    self.left = BST(val)
                else:
                    self.left.add_child(val)
            else:
                if val > self.value:
                    if self.right == None:
                        self.right = BST(val)
                    else:
                        self.right.add_child(val)
        else:
            self.value = val

    def traverse_pre(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.traverse_pre()
        arr.append(self.value)

        if self.right:
            self.right.traverse_pre()


Tree = BST(5)
Tree.add_child(10)
Tree.add_child(8)
Tree.add_child(2)
Tree.add_child(4)
Tree.add_child(7)

Tree.traverse_pre() 
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem like this:

```
def traverse_pre(self):
    rslt = [self.value]
    if self.left:
        rslt.extend(self.left.traverse_pre())

    if self.right:
        rslt.extend(self.right.traverse_pre())
```