# Building a tree in python with tuple

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I get the following tuple :(12, (6, (2,), (8,)), (15, (14,), (18,)))  and I need to return an instance of Tree in the Following form : Tree(12, Tree(6, Tree(2), Tree(8)), Tree(15, Tree(14), Tree(18)))

My class is :

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, entry, left=None, right=None):
        self.entry = entry
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __repr__(self):
        if not self.left and not self.right:
            return "Tree({0})".format(repr(self.entry))
        return "Tree({0},{1},{2})".format(repr(self.entry),repr(self.left),repr(self.right))
```

The problem that I can not understand is why it does not enter to the base condition?
And how can I fix the function.

The function I did is:

```
def build_tree(tree):
    if type(tree) != tuple:
        return Tree(tree)
    return Tree(tree[0], build_tree(tree[1]), build_tree(tree[2]))
```

The activation is :

```
tree1 = (12, (6, (2,), (8,)), (15, (14,), (18,)))
t1=build_tree(tree1)
print(t1)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I get a tuple that is built from 3 elements and I need to return an instance of Tree in the Following form : Tree(12, Tree(6, Tree(2), Tree(8)), Tree(15, Tree(14), Tree(18)))"  As written, this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'll fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the innermost tuples just have one member, avoid using an index that is out of range and just *slice* out whatever there is as tuple members after the node value, and map those to your function.

So replace the last `return` statement in your `build_tree` function with this:

```
return Tree(tree[0], *map(build_tree, tree[1:]))
```

Comment: cute option to avoid IndexError. nice work trincot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `tree[1]` and `tree[2]` are sometimes unset for entries like `(2,)` or `(8,)`.  This will result in an `IndexError`. A workaround is to "pad" the tuple with `(None, None)` values and then trim down to 3 elements -

```py
def build_tree(a):
  if a:
    (entry, left, right) = (a + (None, None))[:3]
    return Tree(entry, build_tree(left), build_tree(right))
  else:
    return None
```

```py
x = (12, (6, (2,), (8,)), (15, (14,), (18,)))
mytree = build_tree(x)
print(mytree)
```

```py
Tree(12,Tree(6,Tree(2),Tree(8)),Tree(15,Tree(14),Tree(18)))
```

I will remark a functional approach with a thin class wrapper will make it easier for you to grow the functionality of your tree. For more information on this technique, see [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340109/633183).

Answer (score -1):

You want `isinstance`

```
def build_tree(tree):
    if isinstance(tree, tuple):
        if len(tree) == 1:
            return Tree(tree[0])
        return Tree(tree[0], build_tree(tree[1]), build_tree(tree[2]))
    return Tree(tree)
```

```
print(build_tree((12, (6, 2, 8), (15, 14, 18))))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the user's homogenous input of `(12, (6, (2,), (8,)), (15, (14,), (18,)))`

Comment: Thanks for the help, still this function does not work for me .
This causes the following error: tuple index out of range

Comment: you added this example post my answer, if all the feeds are tuples then you dont need to check for tuple type at all, just length. I have updated