# Why recursive function is considering last element in an array twice?

Tags: python, class, recursion

Trying to understand recursive functions and so created this program but the output is incorrect. Would like to understand what am I doing wrong here

```py
class Recursive:
    
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        self.sum = 0
        
    def sumRecursive(self):
    
        if len(self.arr) == 0:
            return self.sum
        self.sum = self.arr.pop(0)
        return self.sum + self.sumRecursive()
    
def main():
    recur = Recursive([1,2,3])
    print(recur.sumRecursive())

main()
```

output: `9`

Comment: When programmers design a recursive algorithm, what is the first consideration?

Comment: @quamrana base case

Comment: So, what is your base case?

Comment: why is sum a member variable of the Recursive class? You probably want it to be a local variable of the sumRecursive function. The code there overwrites the sum variable in each call, leaving with a sum of 3 + 3 + 3 when the first call is resolved.

Comment: @quamrana if len(self.arr) == 0:

Comment: Ok, that's the test for the base case. What code needs to be written for that base case?

Comment: @quamrana self.sum = 0 ?

Comment: Your function is not tail-recursive, but you are using an accumulator as if it were.

Comment: Well, the base case says that you are considering an empty array, whose sum is `0`, so just return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of recursion to consider: tail recursion, where the return value of a single recursive call is returned as-is, and "regular" recursion, where you do something with the return value(s) of the recursive call(s) before returning yourself.

You are combining the two. You either add a value from the list to the recursive sum, using no accumulator:

```
def non_tail_recursive(self):
    if len(self.arr) == 0:
        return 0
    return self.arr.pop(0) + self.non_tail_recursive()
```

or you use an accumulator:

```
def tail_recursive(self):
    if len(self.arr) == 0:
         return self.sum

    self.sum += self.arr.pop(0)
    return self.tail_recursive()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Very helpful.

Comment: this is an [oversimplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Recursion_schemes)

Comment: Recursion schemes are somewhat orthogonal to the distinction I'm drawing here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually use an object with state to implement recursion.  If you're keeping state, then you often don't need a recursive solution at all.

Here's how to do a "stateless" recursive sum.

```
def sumRecursive(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0
    return arr[0] + sumRecursive(arr[1:])

def main():
    print(sumRecursive([1,2,3]))

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.sum` attribute is redundant. The information being processed by a recursive algorithm rarely needs members to pass information along.

```py
class Recursive:
    
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        
    def sumRecursive(self):
    
        if not len(self.arr):
            return 0
        return self.arr.pop(0) + self.sumRecursive()
    
def main():
    recur = Recursive([1,2,3])
    print(recur.sumRecursive())

main()
```

Output: `6`

Comment: thank you so much for explaining this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question without rewriting your code (since obviously there are better ways to sum arrays), the answer is that the last leg of your recursion calls `self.sum + self.sumRecursive` which hits your `sumRecursive` function one last time which returns (from your `if` statement) `self.sum` which is the last element in your list (which you already summed).

Instead when the array is empty, return 0.

```
class Recursive:

    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        self.sum = 0
        
    def sumRecursive(self):

        if len(self.arr) == 0:
            return 0 
        self.sum = self.arr.pop(0) 
        return self.sum + self.sumRecursive()


    def main():
        recur = Recursive([1,2,3,4])
        print(recur.sumRecursive())

main()
```

Optionally move your `if` to the bottom where I personally think it makes more sense:

```
def sumRecursive(self):
    self.sum = self.arr.pop(0)  
    if len(self.arr) == 0:
        return self.sum
    else:      
        return self.sum + self.sumRecursive()
```

Answer (score 0):

**fundamentals**

You are making this more challenging for yourself because you are tangling your sum function with the class. The sum function simply needs to work on a list but the context of your object, `self`, is making it hard for you to focus.

Recursion is a functional heritage and this means writing your code in a functional and modular way. It's easier to read/write small, single-purpose functions and it promotes reuse within other areas of your program. Next time you need to sum a list in another class, do you want to rewrite `sumRecursive` again?

Write your summing function once and then `import` it where it's needed -

```py
# mymath.py

def mysum(t):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return t.pop() + mysum(t)
```

See how `mysum` has no concern for context, `self`? Why should it? All it does it sum the elements of a list.

Now write your `recursive` module -

```py
# recursive.py

from mymath import mysum

class Recursive:
  def __init__(self, arr): self.arr = arr
  def sum(self): return mysum(self.arr)
```

See how `Recursive.sum` just hands off `self.arr` to `mysum`? It doesn't have to be more complicated than that. `mysum` will work on every list, not just lists within your `Recursive` module. We don't have to know how `mysum` works, that is the concern of the `mymath` module.

Now we write the `main` module. Each module represents a barrier of abstraction. This means that the details of a module shouldn't spill over into other modules. We don't know how `Recursive` actually sums the input, and from the caller's point of view, we don't care. That is the concern of `Recursive` module.

```py
# main.py

from recursive import Recursive

recur = Recursive([1,2,3])
print(recur.sum())
```

```py
6
```

**going functional**

Above we wrote `mysum` using the `.pop` technique in your question. I did this because that seems to be how you are understanding the problem right now. But watch what happens when we do this -

```py
x = [1,2,3]
print(mysum(x)) # 6
print(mysum(x)) # 0
```

Why does the `mysum` return a different answer the second time? Because as it is written now, `mysum` uses `t.pop()`, which *mutates* `t`. When `mysum` is finished running, `t` is completely emptied!

By why would we write our function like this? What if `5 + x` returned a different result each time we called it?

```py
x = 3
print(5 + x) # 8
print(5 + x) # 8
```

How annoying it would be if we could not depend on values not to change. The sum of the input, `[1,2,3]`, is `6`. But as it is written, the sum of the input is to return `6` **and** empty the input. This second part of emptying (changing) the input is known as a **side effect**. Ie, the *desired effect* is to sum and emptying of the input list is unintended but a consequence of us using `.pop` to calculate the result. This is not the *functional way*. Functional style means *avoiding* mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

```py
def mysum(t):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return t[0] + mysum(t[1:])
```

When written in this way, `t`, is not changed. This allows us to use [equational reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) whereby we can substitute any function call for its return value and **always** get the correct answer

```py
x = [1,2,3]
mysum(x)
== 1 + mysum([2,3])
== 1 + 2 + mysum([3])
== 1 + 2 + 3 + mysum([])
== 1 + 2 + 3 + 0
== 1 + 2 + 3
== 1 + 5
== 6
```

And `x` was not changed as a result of running `mysum` -

```py
print(x)
# [1,2,3]
```

Note, the `Recursive` module does not need to make any change to receive the benefit of rewriting `mysum` in this way. Before the change, we would've seen this behavior -

```py
# main.py

from recursive import Recursive

recur = Recursive([1,2,3])
print(recur.sum())
print(recur.sum())
```

```py
6
0
```

Because the first call to `sum` passes `self.arr` to `mysum` which empties `self.arr` as a side effect. A second call to `recur.sum()` will sum an empty `self.arr`! After fixing `mysum` we get the intended behaviour -

```py
# main.py

from recursive import Recursive

recur = Recursive([1,2,3])
print(recur.sum())
print(recur.sum())
```

```py
6
6
```

**additional reading**

I've written extensively about the techniques used in this answer. Follow the links to see them used in other contexts with additional explanation provided -

- [I want to reverse the stack but i dont know how to use recursion for reversing this… How can i reverse the stack without using Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65532663/633183)
- [Finding all maze solutions with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512563/633183)
- [Return middle node of linked list with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61963040/633183)
- [How do i recursively find a size of subtree based on any given node? (BST)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66723902/633183)
- [Deleting node in BST Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340109/633183)